# Calling same method on different instance (Polymorphism)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, polymorphism

I have situation that 3 different instances with the same method signature are doing their job repeatedly.

```
interface IArgs{
    //args stuff
}

interface IExample{
    void Populate(IArgs);
}

class ExampleA : IExample
{
    void Populate(IArgs a){
        //todo
    }
}

class ExampleB : IExample
{
    void Populate(IArgs b){
        //todo
    }
}

class ExampleC : IExample
{
    void Populate(IArgs c){
        //todo
    }
}


class MainExampleClass(){
    ExampleA classA;
    ExampleB classB;
    ExampleC classC;
    //instantiation and other class stuff
    foreach(Data data in dataCollection){
        classA.Populate(data);
        classB.Populate(data);
        classC.Populate(data);
    }
}
```

It's worth to mention that the classes work with different `args` but I solve that with one dataholder class with all arguments and implementation of an interface (`IArgs`).
So my question is: is there any good way, practice, pattern to solve this repeatedly calling of methods? The Factory pattern, if I understood, will return one instance, but here I need all 3.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I find this question confusing. You are using polymorphism for `IArgs`, but you seem to completely miss polymorphism for `IExample`? Don't overthink this problem, simple array and foreach will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array/list of your `class`es, with their common interface. You can then iterate over it every time you want to `Populate` your classes:

```
class MainExampleClass(){
    ExampleA classA;
    ExampleB classB;
    ExampleC classC;
    //instantiation and other class stuff
    var classes = new IExample[] { classA, classB, classC };
    foreach(Data data in dataCollection){
        foreach (var class_ in classes) {
            class.Populate(data);
        }
    }
}
```